# How two remove same npm from react-native npm

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native, webview

I m new in react-native, i got a issue like this "Invariant Violation: Tried to register two views with the same name RNCWebView "
I check npm ls react-native-webview the i got

├─┬ react-native-instagram-login@2.0.0
│ └── react-native-webview@7.6.0
└── react-native-webview@7.6.0

if i delete outer react-native-webview@7.6.0 then i can not use ┬ react-native-instagram-login@2.0.0
│ └── react-native-webview@7.6.0

if i delete inner webview and i do npm install then again install the inner webview.

I have search lot, but i am able to fix this,

Please help me thank you.